# SpringDataJPA: For @Id, Which @GeneratedValue Strategy can be used for a table already with data not created by SpingDataJPA

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a database table in SQLSerever with some data ( with highest id 360 ).

Now I want to use Spring Data JPA to insert new records into this table.

Is there a way I can make the id of the new records to follow the id of the existing data in an incremental way ( ie 361, 362, and so on)?

Looking for a solution that will not bind me to my current database ( ie, should not prevent me from switching to another database seamlessly in the future )

Answer (score 1):

The only generation type which is fully portable is `GenerationType.TABLE`.

Note that you can use `initialValue` with `@TableGenerator` to skip over the ids already present in your table.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Will use this solution some time in the future as my requirement changed yesterday ( no new record creation needed in the table with data any more ). Much appreciate your help